# The /run directory: how to create it at first boot to store runtime data

Tags: linux, boot

I read an article about the /run directory on Linux systems.
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.devel/146976

This article states that many Linux distributions have agreed that the /run directory is the only clean solution for early-runtime-dir problem. Previously, they put early runtime data in /dev/.XXX or /var/run. But they are now adopting the /run directory for storing early runtime data.

My question: How do they make this change? To be specific, do they change the code in kernel or boot or initscripts?

Take this article (http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.devel/146976) for example, what are the possible changes that needed to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

The `run` directory has no special meaning for the kernel itself be it `/run` or `/var/run`. From the kernel's point of view it is just a regular directory. For performance reasons since some time ago it is usually mounted as `tmpfs` file system. The Fedora distribution creates a symbolic link /var/run pointing to /run for backward compatibility:

mount:

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
```

ls /var:

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    6 Jun  8 15:33 run -> ../run
```

So actually all 'old' programs and scripts will work. But as the convention changed the packages are also undergoing the update to reflect this. So, with time the need in the `/var/run` link will dissappear.

To implement this move of `/run` the init scripts are changed.

Answer (score 1):

`/run` is created and mounted (usually as a tmpfs filesystem) by the init system of your Linux distribution. For example systemd or OpenRC. The init system runs before any other program.

The kernel doesn't have anything to do with it.